# can you combine a high passed signal and low passed signal to get original signal

Tags: filter, signal-processing

suppose you take a signal, and duplicate it, then apply a low pass and high pass filter both with the same frequency and roll-off respectively to each signal, then combine the two signals additively, will that be a good approximate for the original signal? (guessing from some experimentation in audacity, this seems to be true of white noise at least)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you have identical rolloff characteristics - slope and frequency, the mix of the two will be identical to the original signal.

Whether the filter alters phase or not depends entirely on the design of the filter. For instance a basic first order R/C filter will alter the phase by between 45 and 90 degrees depending on slope and frequency. There are many different filter designs which can be emulated by IIR/FIR filters in the digital domain.

As far as frequency and level go, you're good to go.

Comment: I guess this would be the principle of a speaker crossover [not that I know what design elements they may use to prevent phase-shift.]

Comment: This is an interesting article that explains phase in passive R/C Filter networks. https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_2.html

Comment: We are however starting to sidestep into the realms of the electronics stack. Would suggest also to the OP that they could also get a meaningful answer to this question on both the electronics and the dsp stack sites. Would be interesting to see the crosspost and how the perspective of the answer differs.

Comment: Judging by the way I tested this in audacity, the specific filters it uses don't alter phase, as when I combined the two waveforms, subtracting with the original waveform left behind only quiet minor 'glitches' in the waveform.

Comment: @Mark I was considering whether I should post on Electronics or this site, and I settled for this one

Comment: Whether the filter alters phase or not depends entirely on the design of the filter. For instance a basic first order R/C filter will alter the phase by between 45 and 90 degrees depending on slope and frequency. There are many different filter designs which can be emulated by IIR/FIR filters in the digital domain.

Comment: if you add that to the answer, then I will be willing to mark it as accepted

Comment: As requested - done.

Comment: Isn't "the mix of the two will be identical to the original signal" contradictory to the fact that most filters modify phase relationships? Maybe it should be "The frequency spectrum of the mix will be identical"? But phase relationships will be different. So then if you mix that back with another copy of the original signal, do you get some kind of comb-filtering effect?

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure filters always alter the phase relationship when used on a live signal. Think of a square wave, it's not possible for the filter to soften the edge of the wave forward, it can only soften it it by slowing down the rising/falling edges. That means that necessarily the phase is shifted backwards in time. This can be accounted for in a non-live situation with some kind of look-ahead filter.

Comment: phase relationship will be dependent on the type of filter used. You're thinking too much in the time domain, you need to shift your thinking to the frequency domain.